# pip can't find a package even though it's installed

Tags: python, pip, appveyor

When a dependency (`dipy`) is installed with `pip` on an appveyor windows build, the installation fails because a module is not installed (`packaging`).

However, it is installed (in `C:\Python37\lib\site-packages`).

In fact, when we look at the traceback, we'll notice that at first it's `C:\Python37\lib\site-packages` that's used, then when we search for the hook, we switch to `C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-en87c6ej\overlay\Lib\site-packages` (vide infra), where I think `packaging` isn't installed.

I don't understand why this is happening and how to fix it.

```
Collecting dipy (from mia-processes>=2.3.0->populse-mia==2.4.1.dev0+8df8ccf7)
  Downloading dipy-1.7.0.tar.gz (12.4 MB)
     --------------------------------------- 12.4/12.4 MB 29.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [19 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-en87c6ej\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-en87c6ej\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-en87c6ej\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-en87c6ej\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 35, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-1nml3j3e\dipy_a5069f489a1242509a5cd4120d68f564\cythexts.py", line 7, in <module>
      from packaging.version import Version
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Try: `sudo apt install python3-packaging`. I also found solutions which say to update/reinstall pip.

Comment: Thanks to help! It's a Windows build (for CI with appveyor) and I work with cmd (and indeed I'm not confident with cmd windows as I live in a linux environment :-). But I can try to reinstall packaging and pip (I have no idea how to fix this issue so I'm open to ideas!).

Comment: Oh true this is a Windows machine my bad sorry; but on Windows, you can install wsl and then use that xD. Otherwise, I can only say reinstall Python

Comment: The goal is to do unitary test on the 3 platforms linux, macso and windows) so I do not want use wsl. I just tested with `python -m pip install pip --upgrade --force-reinstall` `python -m pip install setuptools --upgrade --force-reinstall` `python -m pip install packaging --upgrade --force-reinstall` with same result. I think the main question is why the traceback show a look in `"C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-q8l70xye\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools` while setuptools is installed in `c:\python37-x64\lib\site-packages` ????

Comment: Is your python interpreter the same as the one used by pip ?

Comment: Thanks to help @Itération122442 !, I have to admit that I can't answer this question definitively. [When we look at the logs](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/populse/populse-mia/builds/47455621/job/kugl7p8afeu1lh07), it's always `C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\` that is used, except when we install `dipy` (L351)... then it looks like we're moving on to another installation ... is it a environment variables issue ?